# What does it mean when a constructor has a type that is the class?

Tags: java, class, data-structures, constructor

I am not quite sure what is going on with `public Amoeba myParent;`.

From what I understand, `myParent`'s type is the class, which I am having a hard time conceptually understanding.  What does that mean?

```
public class AmoebaFamily {

private class Amoeba { // more control on when objects will be created because its private 

        public Amoeba (String name, Amoeba parent) // contructor with arguments 
        {
        myName = name;
        myParent = parent;
        myChildren = new Vector ();
        }
        public String myName;       // amoeba's name
        public Amoeba myParent;     // amoeba's parent
        public Vector myChildren;       // amoeba's children //array that can be resize

        public String toString () { // toString is used whenever you require to explore the constructor called value in string form
            return myName;
        }

        public Amoeba parent () { // constructor without argument just return myParent 
            return myParent;
        }
```

Comment: `public Amoeba parent()` is not a constructor; it's a method.  Just a terminology error there.

Comment: Constructors don't have types in Java; that's not part of the language syntax.

Comment: I think OP is confused about the variable declaration `public Amoeba myParent;` not the method or the constructor.

Comment: @Shobit - Look at the comment to the `parent()` method. That (and the phrasing in the title) suggests that OP is confused about methods and constructors.

Answer (score 2):

The parent of an Amoeba is...an Amoeba.  Let's say our newborn Amoeba is called Amy Jr. and its parent is Amy Sr., you would create an object for Amy Jr. of type Amoeba, and specify that its parent Amy Sr. is also an Amoeba by having a variable myParent of the same type as the child.

If its parent was something else (I don't know how it biologically is possible) like Parrot, you would have something like this to create a new Amoeba whose parent is a Parrot

```
public Amoeba (String name, Parrot parent) // contructor with arguments 
    {
        myName = name;
        myParent = parent;
        myChildren = new Vector ();
    }
    public Parrot myParent;
```

I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is **NOT** a constructor:

```
public Amoeba parent () 
{ 
    return myParent;
}
```

This is simply a method named `parent`, which returns an `Amoeba` object.  The constructor:

```
public Amoeba (String name, Amoeba parent) 
{
    myName = name;
    myParent = parent;
    myChildren = new Vector ();
}
```

initializes an `Amoeba` instance member named `myParent`.  The `parent` method returns said instance member.

Answer (score 0):

A class can have members of its own type, no problem.  This is used all the time to create linked lists.

[Try this](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565927186.do).

Answer (score 0):

It just means that an amoeba is constructed by giving the name of the amoeba, and its parent. And its parent happens to be another amoeba. Just like a folder in a file system has another folder as his parent. Or a human being has two human beings as parents.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to mean that every Amoeba object, when instantiated, will be constructed with a reference to a parent object ... of the same Amoeba type ... I would imagine that if there is such a parent-child structure to these Amoeba objects there will ultimately be an Amoeba that has no parent ... and has a null value at parent ... while the rest will all call some Amoeba object somewhere their parent ... if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Think of this like a family tree.

```
public class Person {
    public Person(String name, Person father, Person mother) { ... }
}
```

It simply mean that to instantiate a new `Amoeba`, you need to first provide it a name and the parent.